# Result of infinite data when return statement include assignment and result

Tags: javascript

```
function test() {
  const data = {};
  return data.test = 'bill' && data;
}

test();
```

Try the above code I got this interesting result in the console when I drill down the object and would love to know why this is happening.[image]

why is test gets keep repeating itself?

Comment: You wrote `return data.test = ('bill' && data)`. Is that what you meant to do? Are you confused about why that’s equivalent to `return data.test = data`?

Comment: `data.test = 'bill' && data` is equivalent to just `data.test = data` - so, a (valid) circular reference is created

Comment: thanks, @JaromandaX I think your answer makes a lot of sense now

Comment: thanks @Ry- I think Jaromanda's answer make sense now